# What does $D^1$ mean?

Tags: general-topology, geometry, notation

This might just be a stupid question but I saw that a torus can be represented as $S^1 \times D^1$ and I know that $S^1$ is a sphere of dimension $1$, so what is $D^1$?

edit: thanks for the answers

Comment: $D^n$ often means $\{x\in\mathbb R^n\mid \|x\|\leq 1\}$ the $n$-dimensional closed unit ball. When $n=1,$ this means $[-1,1].$ But that doesn’t given a torus, so you’ll have to give us more context. Where did you see this? What exactly did they say?

Comment: In general, don’t just say “I saw…” Tell us where you saw it, and in what context. For example, this isn’t true with the usual definition of $D^1,$ or any definition I have seen, so it is likely that you either misunderstood, or the source is wrong. Without an idea of the source, and what exactly is claimed there, we can’t figure out if the source is reliable or not, or what misunderstanding led you to this confusion.

Comment: Evidently you are describing a *solid* torus.  Without any source ascribed, the Question is not "stupid" but [lacks context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30718/what-should-be-acceptable-as-context).  I'm voting to close but will happily vote to reopen if suitably edited.

Answer (score 2):

The one dimensional disc, also known as a closed interval:

$D^1 \cong [0,1]$

Remember that in general, a manifold is called n-dimensional if every neighborhood requires n-coordinates to  be parameterized, So $S^1$ is a circle and $D^2$ is a closed disc.

Comment: I thought about that, but isn't this (i.e., the torus) more naturally defined as $S^1 \times S^1$?  How does the torus wrap around otherwise?

Comment: @Nobel cat, thanks I knew it must have been something simple

Comment: @BrianTung $S^1 \times S^1$ is homeomorphic to a torus but not homeomorphic to either $D^2$, $S^2$ or anything I mentioned so I'm a bit confused at your statement

Comment: @boba but with this definition, $S^1\times D^1$ is not a torus, it is just a cylinder.

Comment: $S^1 \times D^2$ is not homeomorphic to a cylinder, but rather a solid torus. $D^2 \times D^1$ is homeomorphic to a solid cylinder and $S^1 \times D^1$ is homeomorphic to a shell of a tube edit: $S^1 \times D^2$ is a solid torus not $S^1 \times D^1$ >.<

Comment: @NobelCat: What I mean is that I think your interpretation of $D^1$ is fine in isolation, but in the context of defining the torus as $S^1 \times D^1$, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $S^1 \times D^1$ is not supposed to be homeomorphic to a torus (unless ysou identify the boundary points or D^1$ with eachother)

Comment: The OP states that their source claims that the torus can be "represented" as $S^1 \times D^1$.  Whatever that means (and therein lies the problem).

Comment: ah, so he did, Gotcha. Yeah, that's not correct!

Comment: @NobelCat the question says a torus can be “represented by” $S^1\times D^1.$ Without clarifying what is meant by “represented by,” it certainly makes sense to treat that as homeomorphism. But again, this is the risk of answering a question before asking thOP to clarify with the source and what is meant.

Answer (score 0):

In general $D^n= \{x \in \Bbb R^n\mid \|x\|_n \le 1\}$, the unit disk of $n$ dimensions (the norm being the usual Euclidean one with the square root of the sum of squares in general, and absolute value in one dimension). Its boundary (so with $\|x\|_n= 1$ instead), is called $S^{n-1}$ (it has one topological dimension less.) So for $n=1$ we get $[-1,1]$ (homeomorphic to any closed non-trivial bounded interval in $\Bbb R$) and $S^0 = \{-1,1\}$ a two point discrete space.

To visualise $S^1 \times D^1$, image a circle $S^1$) in the $xy$-plane and for each point of the circle a copy of $D^1 = [-1,1]$ vertically attached to it, going parallel to the $z$-axis. So we get $\{(x,y,x)\mid x^2+y^2=1; -1 \le z \le 1\}$ which is the "mantle" of a cylinder in $\Bbb R^3$ (no top or bottom disk). This is what topologists call a cylinder.